# SQL : getting the authorisation levels of employees for certain projects

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, authorization

I am working on a web app for our company's employees. Based on certain training that they had and procedures that they read, a certain employee can be authorised to work in a certain project.

I have several tables:

- `vw_Employee` (stores all the employee records and has a primary key for identification called "Sicil")
- `tbl_yet_Proje` (stores all the projects available in the company at that time and has a primary identification key called "Proj_ID")
- `tbl_yet_ProjeEgitim` (stores training prerequisites for a given project, stores two identification keys: one is Proj_ID and the other is TR_ID to identify which training is needed for the corresponding project)
- `tbl_yet_ProjeProsedur` (just like tbl_yet_ProjeEgitim this one stores procedure prerequisites for a given project, stores two identification keys: one is Proj_ID and the other is Pros_ID to identify which procedure is needed for the corresponding project)
- `tbl_yet_EmployeeEgitim` and `tbl_yet_EmployeeProsedur` (just like `tbl_yet_ProjeEgitim` and `tbl_yet_ProjeProsedur` these two stores which employee took which training and read which procedure respectively. They store two identification keys each: "Sicil" to identify the employee and TR_ID and Pros_ID respectively, to see what training they got or what procedures they read)

I want to select a table that simply shows the "Sicil" of the employee and "Proj_ID" of the projects that they can work in. Which means they have at least took the trainings and read the procedures that is the prerequisite of a project. If they did more than that, it's OK. I want to do this for the entire database and find every employee's project that they are authorised and can possibly work on.

I have gotten this far in my SQL query but it is not accurate. I am guessing that it has got something to do with there being so many join operations:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    emp.Sicil, proj.Proj_ID
FROM
    tbl_yet_Proje proj 
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    tbl_yet_ProjeEgitim pe ON proj.Proj_ID = pe.Proj_ID
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_yet_ProjeProsedur pp on proj.Proj_ID = pp.Proj_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_yet_EmployeeEgitim ee ON pe.TR_ID = ee.TR_ID
INNER JOIN 
    tbl_yet_EmployeeProsedur ep ON ep.Pros_ID = pp.Pros_ID
INNER JOIN 
    vw_Employee emp ON emp.Sicil = ep.Sicil AND emp.Sicil = ee.Sicil
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you so much

Comment: ??? MySQL or SQLServer ??? Please dont spam tags

Comment: It's an SQLServer sorry, I have just edited it

Comment: if you don't want nulls returned from any table then you need inner join instead of full outer.

Comment: Thank you, I did that and deleted the where statement but it still shows that some employees are allowed to work ar certain projects even though they should not be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a cross join between employees and projects filtering the ones for which there is a procedure or a training not accomplished by the employee. If I am not wrong the following query should give you the result you are willing to gather:

```
select e.Sicil,
       proj.Proj_ID
  from tbl_yet_Proje proj,
       vw_Employee e
 where (
         select count(*) 
           from tbl_yet_ProjeProsedur pp 
                left join tbl_yet_EmployeeProsedur ep on pp.Pros_ID = ep.Pros_ID
                                                         and ep.Sicil = e.Sicil
          where pp.Proj_ID = proj.Proj_ID
                and ep.Pros_ID is null
       ) = 0
       and (
         select count(*) 
           from tbl_yet_ProjeEgitim pt
                left join tbl_yet_EmployeeEgitim et on pt.TR_ID = ep.TR_ID 
                                                       and et.Sicil = e.Sicil
          where pt.Proj_ID = proj.Proj_ID
                and et.TR_ID is null                    
       ) = 0
```

Comment: I am sorry but now it just shows the employees and projects without regarding anything

Comment: You are totally correct: my where statement's sub-queries were missing the filter by employee. Now it should work correctly.

Comment: Yea, I'm sorry. It still gives the same outcome :/

Comment: OK I figured out what was incorrect: now I included the condition of the employee ID in the JOIN statement and it should work. For the future I would suggest that you create the case in a SQL Fiddle to ease the testing, otherwise we cannot test the solutions provided.